# Can't access prop in has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :metric, dependent: :destroy
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And for some reason that I don't fully understand, I can't create a new metric through a post:

```
> post = Post.first 1
> post.metric # => Nil
> post.metric.create # NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass)
```

Do I have to declare anything else any of my models to make this work?

Comment: try `post.build_metric` or `post.create_metric`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call create method on `nil` class.

[Active Record Associations DOC](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference)

```
post = Post.first 1
post.build_metric # will be automatically assigned post_id to metrics but not saved
post.save
#or
post.create_metric # will be automatically assigned post_id to metrics and saved
```

Alternate solution:

`Metric.create(post_id: post.id)`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is

```
post = Post.first 1
# You don't tell us what this evaluates to, but I'm assuming a post as the #metric call works

post.metric # => Nil
# You have nil

post.metric.create
# Now you're calling the create method on nil.
```

What you need to do is

```
Metric.create(post_id: Post.first.id, etc_attribute: etc_value, ...)
```

EDIT: Also what 7urkm3n said in his comment-- build_metric and create_metric are cleaner solutions that utilize Rails magic.